# Can I get the tensorflow session from the estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using the LinearRegressor of tf.estimator and want to change my learning rate decay (originally exponential decay) to the decay that use the loss. But to do this, I need to pass the evaluation loss to some placeholders of learning rate decay tensor, and during this step, I need tf.session.

I tried `tf.get_default_session()` to get the session that is made by estimator, but this session has different graph that used by estimator.

```py
    def my_decay(learning_rate, global_step, decay_step, loss, decay_rate):
      # If loss is not reduced, than decay with decay_rate.

    loss = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    optimizer==lambda: tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
        learning_rate=my_decay(learning_rate=0.1,
        global_step=tf.get_global_step(), decay_step=10000,
        loss=loss, decay_rate=0.96)),
      config=sess_config
    )

    for _ in range(n_epoches):
      metrics = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
      session.run(loss.assign(metrics['loss']))
```

With above code, I need to get `session` from the estimator.
Is there any way to get this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Short answer is you can't. If you absolutely need to access session, use monitored session. But i'm pretty sure you can define custom loss decay without session, if only you'd be more specific

Comment: @Sharky , Thank you for your answer. It seems that using a monitored session is not recommended in general. But is it possible that extracting the loss from the estimator and passing it to `my_decay`?

Comment: I think you can use `estimator.get_variable_value`, pass name to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended solution for something like this is to subclass [`tf.train.SessionRunHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SessionRunHook) and override the `before_run` method to return a suitable [`tf.train.SessionRunArgs`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SessionRunArgs). This will allow you to feed values at train time and add fetches to the `session.run` call. Your class will have to carry a reference to the placeholder and the `loss` state in-between the calls.

Then you simply instantiate the class and add the hook to the `hooks` parameter in your `estimator.train` call or in this case your `train_spec`. If you wish to use the evaluation loss instead of the training loss then this can be achieved by adding another hook to the `eval_spec` that reads out the values in the `after_run` method.

Comment: didn't get you clearly, can you give some code sample?